# AssertionError: size of input tensor and input format are different. - Tensorboard add image

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

I have tried to add an image to the tensorboard.

```
img = Image.open(image_path)

img = (np.asarray(img) / 255.0)
img = torch.from_numpy(img).float()
img = img.cuda().permute(2, 0, 1)
img = img.cuda().unsqueeze(0)

writer.add_image('Original', img)
```

but there is an error.

> tensor shape: {}, input_format: {}".format(tensor.shape, input_format)
> AssertionError: size of input tensor and input format are different.         tensor shape: (1, 3, 420, 629), input_format: CHW

Answer (score 0):

looks like your using the function to add a single image but you are adding a batch of images of size 1.
if you don't want to reshape/flatten/mess with the `img` try specifying the `dataformats` parameter and use `add_images`:

```
writer.add_images('Original', img, dataformats='NCHW')
```

> img_tensor: Default is (N, 3, H, W)(N,3,H,W). If dataformats is
> specified, other shape will be accepted. e.g. NCHW or NHWC.

source [SummaryWriter.add_image](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter.add_images)